# I cannot run conda command /activate environment on ubuntu?

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, conda

I have installed anaconda in `ubuntu` and am facing a problem with anaconda. I was running the following command in a conda environment:

```
271  pip install --user -r requirements.txt
  272  cd ..
  273  conda install ipython jupyter
  274  conda install jupyter
  275  python
  276  sudo apt-get install python-vtk python-wxgtk2.6 python-setuptools python-numpy python-configobj
  277  sudo apt-get install python-vtk python-wxgtk2.8 python-setuptools python-numpy python-configobj
  278  conda install -c anaconda mayavi==4.5.0
```

It suddenly stopped working. Once I want to activate an environment or run any command with `conda`, I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

I have even added `export PATH=/home/user/anaconda2/bin:$PATH` to `.bashrc`. Could someone please help?

Comment: How did you install conda and what command did you run before you got this error?

Comment: I updated the question. please have a look. I wanted to install the requirements for a software. I really appreciate if you can help.

Comment: Did you try to `pip install conda` before the error came ?

Comment: @NikhilFadnis yes i just had a look on history, yes I have done

Comment: once I ran this `which conda` , it is showing the path to the bin directory, but it is not recognizing any conda commands.

Comment: I'd recommend you keep your Anaconda installation separate from your regular python one. You've mixed up pip, apt-get and conda itself in your setup.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install conda` can corrupt the conda setup. Download miniconda setup from the path in the error and run below

`bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -f`

To test your installation, enter the command `conda --version`. If installed correctly, you will see the version of conda installed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. One question is that will it corrupt my environments in anaconda?

Comment: Make sure you reinstall on the same path as before so the only the core conda files will be replaced.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help